# How do I rebase my pull request onto master in github?

Tags: git, github

I wanted to work on some others repository in GitHub. So, I forked the repo and made a new branch and put a pull request on that branch. Now, the main repository has been updated. And I need to rebase my pull request onto master. I am very new to git and github. I tried different tutorials but not got the point clearly. Can anyone please explain me how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Pull Request is generic to your branch. Pull the latest code, commit any further changes, push it to your branch and re-create a pull request. Your new changes will be updated to your pull request.

Note: If the owner of the repository is going to merge the code, then he/she would definitely have an updated code base before the merge. Think if you really want to do the same as an extra work.

Comment: Yes, just select the branch on your fork on GitHub, update it there, then pull locally. I am happy that it is that simple these days. Carambas solution may be correct, but I get depressed by just looking at all the commands I have to learn and execute and remember.

Answer (score 1):

So you created already a PR (Pull Request) which is good.

**Step 1**
Make sure you pushed all your changes into that PR so just do those commands if needed again:

```
git add .
git commit -m 'last changes'
git push origin my-pr-branch
```

Then leave this as it is. So if you got merge conflicts and stuff that can give you some work you need to solve. So clone the repository again into a different folder and just check there if you can merge. If you can all good. If not you have a copy. So you can do everything locally and before you push it it's just in a directory on your local computer. If you think oh my gosh this is to much work you can jump to Step 3.

**Step 2** Create a new directory and clone the repository. Something like

```
cd ~/Desktop
mkdir test-repo-merge
cd test-repo-merge
git clone bling-bling-bling-repository
cd bling-bling-bling-repository
```

**Step 3**
check if you are on the right branch, check out to master branch and just pull again, even though you just cloned it.

```
git branch -a
git co master
git pull origin master
git fetch origin --prune
```

**Step 4** the fun part

```
git co my-pr-branch
git rebase -
```

if no merge conflicts you are good to go with a

```
git push origin my-pr-branch -f
```

else yo need to resolve the merge conflicts. The command line will give you advices what you need to do. Just read them carefully.

Comment: Thank you @caramba. I did what you said. I got comments such as:

Comment: Sorry for the last comment. Anyway I did what you said. I got  `Already up-to-date` comment for `git pull original master` command and  `current branch my-pr-branch is up to date` comment for rebase command. It seemed that everything is now updated. Then I updated it to remote my-pr-branch. But I found no update in my repo. I think my-pr-branch has been updated to the master branch of my repo. But I want to update my-pr-branch to the main repo from where I forked my repo. It is some others repo and the main repo has been updated by some one else. I want to update my repo and my pr to the main.

Comment: Please suggest what to do?